# Resize Bitmap only if too large

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I would like to resize each photo taken with camera only if the photo is too large (e.g only of width > 2048px).

I've seen on the official doc

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
     options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

and

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

but this code involve that I know the final size.
What I want to do do is to reduce by 50% if it is really too large, or only 20% if the bitmap is not too large, etc. (depend of the smartphone's camera...)

The method calculateInSampleSize() seems to do what I want and the doc says " For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384" but I do not want to set a final width/height.

Then, when I get the smaller bitmap, I want to make a

```
scaledBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
```

to optimize again.

How can I solve this please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I chose another solution:

```
public static void resizeBitmapOnFileSystem(String originalPath, File photoCompressedFile) throws IOException {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(originalPath, options);

    int minimalLengthSide = 300; //Minimal length of the shorter side of the picture. Used to calculate the best 'scale' value.
    int scale = calculateInSampleSize(options, minimalLengthSide, minimalLengthSide);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
    try {
        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(photoCompressedFile);

        scaledBitmap = loadScaledBitmap(originalPath, scale);
        if (scaledBitmap != null) {
            scaledBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, out);
            fo.write(out.toByteArray());
        }
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fo);
        recycleQuietly(scaledBitmap);
    }
}

/**
 * From offical Android documentation
 * @param options
 * @param reqWidth
 * @param reqHeight
 * @return
 */
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Even if the `resizeBitmapOnFileSystem()` method is not very "handy", the trick is the `minimalLengthSide` variable. I set the minimal length of the shorter side I want (here, 300px), and the method `calculateInSampleSize()` will automatically calculate the appropriate scale.

Ratio width/height is kept and I do not use 
`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width, height, filter)`
which may be "costly" or less efficient.

Comment: Also what is IOUtils ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get width and height of the bitmap as `bitmap.getWidth()` and `bitmap.getHeight()`. Once you have width and height, check which one's value is smaller. If width is smaller than height, store `width` in one variable called `value` else  store `height`.

And then you can compress the bitmap by checking value as follows.

```
Bitmap bitmap = your bitmap;

int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();

int value;
if (width < height) {
    value = width;
} else {
    value = height;
}

Bitmap scaledBitmap;

if (value > 5000) {
    scaledBitmap = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
} else if (value > 4000) {
    scaledBitmap = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, out);
} else if (value > 3000) {
    scaledBitmap = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out);
} else if (value > 2048) {
    scaledBitmap = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, out);
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want because I do not want a test on each dimension... but it probably works...